# Retrieve spotify album covers of currently played songs

Tags: api, spotify, playlist

Hej,

I'd like to retrieve the cover artworks of my current listenings and put it in a way like this:

```
[http://codepen.io/motorlatitude/pen/hipIl][1]
```

I found a couple of solution on how to get the album covers in general, but not for my recent listenings only.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Spotify Web API has an endpoint for returning the cover artwork of a given album, see the `images` property in the information return in [Get Album](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-album/).

However, Spotify doesn't expose recent listenings, so you'll need to get that information somehow. Some people use Last.FM API, that can give you this information if you scrobble to Last.fm from Spotify or any music player.